# STM32F1xx CAN2 receive interrupt not being called

Tags: c, interrupt, stm32, can-bus

I've successfully established CAN communication with CAN1 of two STM32F105vC(s)(Which has two CANs), and I can send and receive CAN frames.

But when I change my code to use CAN2, it works, I mean it acknowledges the received CAN frames but the **receive interrupt is not being called at all**.

I thought it's filter configuration, I changed the BankNumber multipletimes (tried 0, 1, 14, 20), no luck.

Here is my configurations:

Initilizing:

```
init_HAL_CAN(CAN2);

if(HAL_CAN_Receive_IT(canHandle, CAN_FIFO0) != HAL_OK)
{
    /* Reception Error */
    Error_Handler();
}
```

Receive callback:

```
void HAL_CAN_RxCpltCallback(CAN_HandleTypeDef* CanHandle)
{
    LED_DBG_TOGGLE();

    // other 
    // stuff 
    // here
    //...

    /* Receive */
    if(HAL_CAN_Receive_IT(CanHandle, CAN_FIFO0) != HAL_OK)
    {
        /* Reception Error */
        Error_Handler();
    }
}
```

Init function:

```
void init_HAL_CAN(CAN_TypeDef* _CANInstance)
{
    CAN_FilterConfTypeDef sFilterConfig;
    static CanTxMsgTypeDef TxMessage;
    static CanRxMsgTypeDef RxMessage;

    /*##-1- Configure the CAN peripheral #######################################*/
    canHandle->Instance = _CANInstance;
    canHandle->pTxMsg = &TxMessage;
    canHandle->pRxMsg = &RxMessage;
    canHandle->Init.TTCM = DISABLE; //Non time trigger communication mode //
    canHandle->Init.ABOM = DISABLE;  //The software automatically Bus-off management     //
    canHandle->Init.AWUM = DISABLE; //Sleep mode wake by software (clear CAN-> MCR SLEEP) (automatic wake-up mode)//
    canHandle->Init.NART = DISABLE;  //Disable automatic transfer message (non-automatic retransmission mode)//
    canHandle->Init.RFLM = DISABLE; //The message is not locked, the new cover the old // 
    canHandle->Init.TXFP = DISABLE; // Priority is determined by the message identifier //

    canHandle->Init.Mode = CAN_MODE_NORMAL;
    canHandle->Init.SJW = CAN_SJW_1TQ;
    canHandle->Init.BS1 = CAN_BS1_2TQ;
    canHandle->Init.BS2 = CAN_BS2_1TQ;
    canHandle->Init.Prescaler = 7;

    if(HAL_CAN_Init(canHandle) != HAL_OK)
    {
        /* Initialization Error */
        Error_Handler();
        return false;
    }

    /*##-2- Configure the CAN Filter ###########################################*/
    CAN_FilterConfTypeDef sFilterConfig;
    sFilterConfig.FilterNumber = 0;
    sFilterConfig.FilterMode = CAN_FILTERMODE_IDMASK;
    sFilterConfig.FilterScale = CAN_FILTERSCALE_32BIT;
    sFilterConfig.FilterIdHigh = 0x0000;
    sFilterConfig.FilterIdLow = 0x0000;
    sFilterConfig.FilterMaskIdHigh = 0x0000;
    sFilterConfig.FilterMaskIdLow = 0x0000;
    sFilterConfig.FilterFIFOAssignment = 0;
    sFilterConfig.FilterActivation = ENABLE;
    sFilterConfig.BankNumber = 20;

    if (HAL_CAN_ConfigFilter(canHandle, &sFilterConfig) != HAL_OK)
    {
        /* Filter configuration Error */
        Error_Handler();
        return false;
    }

}
```

IRQHandler (placed in stm32f1xx_it.c):

```
void CAN2_RX0_IRQHandler(void)
{
    HAL_CAN_IRQHandler(canHandle);
}
```

MspInit function (placed in stm32f1xx_hal_msp.c) :

```
void HAL_CAN_MspInit(CAN_HandleTypeDef *hcan)
{
    GPIO_InitTypeDef   GPIO_InitStruct;

    /*##-1- Enable peripherals and GPIO Clocks #################################*/
    /* CAN1 Periph clock enable */
    CANx1_CLK_ENABLE(); // Need to enable CAN1 clock too.
    CANx2_CLK_ENABLE();
    /* Enable GPIO clock ****************************************/
    CANx2_GPIO_CLK_ENABLE();
    /* CAN2 needs no remapping *******/

    /*##-2- Configure peripheral GPIO ##########################################*/
    /* CAN1 TX GPIO pin configuration */
    GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = CANx2_TX_PIN;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_AF_PP;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_HIGH;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_PULLUP;

    HAL_GPIO_Init(CANx2_TX_GPIO_PORT, &GPIO_InitStruct);

    /* CAN1 RX GPIO pin configuration */
    GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = CANx2_RX_PIN;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_AF_PP;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_HIGH;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_PULLUP;

    HAL_GPIO_Init(CANx2_RX_GPIO_PORT, &GPIO_InitStruct);

    /*##-3- Configure the NVIC #################################################*/
    /* NVIC configuration for CAN2 Reception complete interrupt */

    HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(CAN2_RX0_IRQn, 1, 0);
    HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(CAN2_RX0_IRQn);

}
```

I should mention again, that following codes works perfectly with **CAN1** (of course with changing CAN2 to CAN1, etc).

And it's clear that the CAN controller is working because the other board that is transmitting CAN frames, **receives the acknowledges** (and does not get any transmitting error or timeout), the only problem here is **Receive Interrupts**, why?

Answer (score 3):

I had similar issue and what help was reference manual:

CAN2SB[5:0]: CAN2 start bank

These bits are set and cleared by software. They define the start bank for the CAN2
interface (Slave) in the range 0 to 27.

**Note: When CAN2SB[5:0] = 28d, all the filters to CAN1 can be used.**

When CAN2SB[5:0] is set to 0, no filters are assigned to CAN1
sFilterConfig.BankNumber = 20;

Please change
  `sFilterConfig.BankNumber = 20;`

to

`sFilterConfig.BankNumber = 0x2d;`

Comment: Docs say that BankNumber should be between 0 and 28, to enable all can filters for CAN2, not CAN1, the value should be 0. I think 0x2d only somehow works because of overflow, because that evaluates to 45, well past the suggest values in the docs.

Comment: I don't get this magic number 0x2d, but it works somehow.

But.. If I set `CAN_SlaveStartBank(14);` *and* `CAN_FilterNumber = 14;`, then it starts working as intended.

Answer (score 0):

You must perform settings of all filters through hcan1. Even for Can2.

> In connectivity line
>   devices, the registers from offset 0x200 to 31C are present only in CAN1.

...and on offset 0x200 begins filter settings...